# Missed Comma in APA bibliography with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, apa6

I use `biblatex` with `apa` style to produce my bibliography. With LibreOffice get this result:

[image]

with `biblatex` I get:

[image]

As you can see, the result is without comma.

What can I do to get rid with this problem?

My MWE

```
\documentclass[man,a4paper,nolmodern,babel,american,french]{apa6}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname1.bib}
@Article{Hoppe2016,
 Title = {Learning rational temporal eye movement strategies.},
 Author= {Hoppe, David and Rothkopf, Constantin A.},
Journal= {PNAS Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of the United States of America},
 Year= {2016},
 Number = {29},
Pages = {8332 - 8337},
 Volume= {113},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname1.bib}
\title{Étude du potentiel évoqué dans l'apprentissage du vocabulaire d'une première langue étrangère }

\author{Some one}
\date{}

\AtBeginBibliography{% 
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
\finalandcomma
\addspace
\bibstring{and}%
\space
}}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Méthode}
Bla bla 

Blah blah blah~ \cite{Hoppe2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\finalandcomma` is language dependant, your main language is french, and in french imho there is no comma there. (I also don't get an `&` but `et`.)

Comment: Thank you,but if I want the body in french and the bibliography in english(american) what can I do ?

Comment: Try \selectlanguage{american} before the bibliographie. You will need also a \DeclareLanguageMapping for american.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up an answer here, so we can wrap this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the following MWE (important changings marked with `<=======`):

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Hoppe2016,
  Title   = {Learning rational temporal eye movement strategies.},
  Author  = {Hoppe, David and Rothkopf, Constantin A.},
  Journal = {PNAS Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences of 
             the United States of America},
  Year    = {2016},
  Number  = {29},
  Pages   = {8332 - 8337},
  Volume  = {113},
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[man,a4paper,nolmodern,babel,american,french]{apa6}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa} % <=====================
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\title{Étude du potentiel évoqué dans l'apprentissage du vocabulaire 
       d'une première langue étrangère}
\author{Some one}
\date{}

\AtBeginBibliography{% 
  \renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
    \finalandcomma % language dependent
    \addspace
    \&%\bibstring{and}% & instead of and
    \space
  }%
}


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Méthode}
Bla bla 

Blah blah blah~\cite{Hoppe2016}

\selectlanguage{american} % <===========================================
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

gives you an american bibliography including `, and`:

[image: resulting bibliography]